# Set Bitmap to my layout background

Tags: android, android-bitmap, setbackground

I'm downloading the image from URL and using this bitmap to my layout background. I can't able to see my image.

I'm struggle with this for past two days. Still now i cant able to find a solution. I have googled a lot. Please help me wrong misktake i done.

Thanks a lot in advance.

MY CODE:

```
Bitmap myImage = getBitmapFromURL("http://looksok.files.wordpress.com/2011/12/me.jpg");


        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16){
            setBackgroundV16Plus( myImage);
        }
        else{
            setBackgroundV16Minus( myImage);
        }

@TargetApi(16)
    private void setBackgroundV16Plus(  Bitmap bitmap) {
        linearLayout.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(getApplicationContext().getResources(), bitmap));

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private void setBackgroundV16Minus(  Bitmap bitmap) {
        linearLayout.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(bitmap));
    }

    public Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String imageUrl) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            return myBitmap;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please mention here if you getting any exception

Comment: First point request is https instead of http. also add `connection.setRequestMethod("GET");` before `connection.connect();` line for GET request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private class LoadProfileImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    public LoadProfileImage() {

    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.println(Log.ASSERT, "error", "" + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bitmap;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
     myImage=result;
    }
}
```

for calling method for downloading image

```
 new LoadProfileImage().execute("http://looksok.files.wordpress.com/2011/12/me.jpg");
```

this statement to download image and store to your bitmap variable now  set the background

and add the Internet permission on manifest.

Comment: in expection and also bitmap is null

Answer (score 2):

```
RelativeLayout relative = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative1);
Drawable dr = new BitmapDrawable(bit);
(view).setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
```

Comment: always my bitmap returns null

Answer (score 0):

For connect to internet you must used Thrad or AsynkTask

```
public class MyAyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void,Void>{

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Bitmap myImage = getBitmapFromURL("http://looksok.files.wordpress.com/2011/12/me.jpg");
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: always my bitmap returns null

Answer (score 0):

Use picasso library it's easy to use
here is the link of picasso example

http://javatechig.com/android/how-to-use-picasso-library-in-android